# High School Football Stats

Tags: usa, api, sports

I am in a application development course (CSC 400), required for my Computer Science major, and have been asked to create a "web scrapper" utility that harvests data of high school football statistics. I have been searching for APIs but cannot find any. There are plenty for NFL and college football but none for high school that I can find. I found the website: http://www.maxpreps.com/ which has the data I need but they do not offer developer APIs; and scraping html from this site would be extremely tedious, and perhaps unethical. Could anyone please recommend any APIs or data feeds that are available for consumption?

Comment: Are you looking for nationwide HS football data, or for a specific region?

Comment: Nationwide preferable.

Comment: You could try import.io they have a service that does the web scraping for you. So far I had good experiences finding datasets on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/search?q=football&restrict_sr=on (or requesting them if I did not find it).